# How to get the past tense of a word using nltk and WordNet in Python?

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

What are the packages required to run the below commands?

#### Code

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
v = 'go'
present = present_tense(v)
I got an error saying-
```

#### Error message

> NameError: name 'present_tense' is not defined

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Nltk and Wordnet how do i convert simple tense verb into its present, past or past participle form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753021/using-nltk-and-wordnet-how-do-i-convert-simple-tense-verb-into-its-present-past)

Comment: i picked up the commands from there. He hasn't mentioned the packages which need to be imported. Could you please help me?

Comment: Apps, they were asking how to implement a `present_tense` function, not importing an existing function.

Comment: The en package is the NodeBox English Linguistics Library, referenced in the comment by @larsmans

Answer (score 3):

You may try: `import en`
instead of:  `import nltk`

You may try: `en.verb.present(v)`
instead of:  `present_tense(v)`

The en package is from the [NodeBox English Linguistics library](http://nodebox.net/code/index.php/Linguistics)

Demo site: http://wnbot.com/wordnet/stackoverflow.py

Draft source code listing:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import en
import sys

went = 'went'
going = 'going'
gone = 'gone'
goes = 'goes'

print "Content-Type: text/html"
print
print "<html><head><title>Stack Overflow answer</title></head><body>"
print ' The present tense of <b>',going, '</b> is <i>',en.verb.present(going),'</i><br>'
print ' The present tense of <b>',goes, '</b> is <i>',en.verb.present(goes),'</i><br>'
print ' The present tense of <b>',gone, '</b> is <i>',en.verb.present(gone),'</i><br>'
print ' The present tense of <b>',went, '</b> is <i>',en.verb.present(went),'</i><br>'
print "</body></html>"
```

This source code listing is a draft for educational and discussion purposes only.

Comment: Hello, isn't this info now not useful for python 3+