# Why does the nltk lemmatizer not work for every word in Python?

Tags: python, string, nltk, lemmatization, nltk-trainer

```
import ntlk
lemmatizer = ntlk.WordNetLemmatizer()
print(lemmatizer.lemmatize("goes"))
print(lemmatizer.lemmatize("transforming"))
```

The first example will with "goes" do work. The output is: "go". The second does not work. I get the output "transforming" but should be "transform".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the tag 'v' to have the lemmatizer interpret the word as a verb. If you don't it will assume it is a noun.

```
>>> lemmatizer.lemmatize("transforming")
'transforming'
>>> lemmatizer.lemmatize("transforming", "v")
'transform'
```

There are some helpful answers for you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25534214/nltk-wordnet-lemmatizer-shouldnt-it-lemmatize-all-inflections-of-a-word).

Comment: Are there anymore than verb I need to pass in?

Comment: You need to look into Parts of Speech tagging. The answers in the link go more into how you can do this.