# Verb tense conversion in Python

Tags: python, nlp, linguistics, nodebox-linguistics

I'm trying to convert certain verbs to other tenses for some NLP task.

I'm trying to use the NodeBox::Linguistics library as suggested here:
[Using NLTK and WordNet; how do I convert simple tense verb into its present, past or past participle form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753021/using-nltk-and-wordnet-how-do-i-convert-simple-tense-verb-into-its-present-pas)

But I find that this code does not print the correct form of the word:

```
print en.verb.present("found")
print en.verb.infinitive("found")
```

I expect it to print 'find' but it actually just prints 'found'.

1. Is this a bug in the library or am I missing something?
2. Would you recommend using any other library for any other reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nodebox uses Ogden Basic English word list (2000).
https://www.nodebox.net/code/index.php/Linguistics#ogden

From what I see it looks like 'Found' is not part of that list..
http://ogden.basic-english.org/word2000.html