# How to check if string consist of consonant, vowel and consonant?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Lets say I have a list of strings `verbs = ["win", "dig", "be", "go", "break]` etc. I figured out how to duplicate last letter and add "ing" to them. However how can I check if characters in those strings consisting of consonant-vowel-consonat?
I have two lists:

```
vowel = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
consonant = ["b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
```

and here is code sample:

```
for ver in verbs:
    if verb "I DON'T KNOW WHAT TO TYPE HERE":
        verb = verb[:len(verb)] + verb[len(verb) - 1: len(verb)] + "ing"
        - then do sth
```

Comment: Side note: `verb[:len(verb)]` gives you the whole word, the slice is meaningless; just use `verb` instead. You can use negative numbers in slices, these are automatically subtracted from `len(object)`, and you can *omit* slice components to leave them to the default (being start and end), so `verb[len(verb) - 1: len(verb)]` can be expressed as `verb[-1:]`, or for strings, `verb[-1]` suffices. So it's `verb = verb + verb[-1] + 'ing'`. Or just `verb += verb[-1] + 'ing'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use *sets*, for fast membership testing:

```
import string

vowel = set("aeiou")
consonant = set(string.ascii_lowercase) - vowel   # all letters that are not vowels
```

then just see if those last 3 letters are in the sets:

```
if len(verb) > 2 and verb[-3] in consonant and verb[-2] in vowel and verb[-1] in consonant:
    verb += verb[-1] + 'ing'
```

or a little more compact using strict subset testing:

```
if len(verb) > 2 and {verb[-3], verb[-1]} <= consonant and verb[-2] in vowel:
    verb += verb[-1] + 'ing'
```

The `verb += verb[-1] + 'ing'` statement uses augmented assignment to append the last letter plus `'ing'` to the `verb` string value. Negative indices count from the end of the sequence, so `-1` gives you the last letter in a string:

```
>>> verb[-1]
'k'
```

Demo:

```
>>> for verb in verbs:
...     if len(verb) > 2 and {verb[-3], verb[-1]} <= consonant and verb[-2] in vowel:
...         verb += verb[-1] + 'ing'
...     else:
...         verb += 'ing'
...     print(verb)
...
winning
digging
being
going
breaking
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want verb[0], verb[1] and verb[2]? Negatives would be out of range wouldn't they?

Comment: @emsimpson92: because it is the *last 3 characters* that should be tested, not the first three. Negative indices count from the end.

Comment: I must have missed that specification.

Comment: @emsimpson92: [Here it is](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html?highlight=negative#slicings): "If either bound is negative, the sequence’s length is added to it."

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that use some NLP package like NodeBox or nltk to do this instead of writing custom code to append `ing`. There might be some case that you may miss.

Some answers here might be helpful:

[Using NLTK and WordNet; how do I convert simple tense verb into its present, past or past participle form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753021/using-nltk-and-wordnet-how-do-i-convert-simple-tense-verb-into-its-present-pas/3761041)

This library is also very helpful
https://www.nodebox.net/code/index.php/Linguistics#verb_conjugation

An example:

```
import en
print en.verb.present_participle("be")
```

> being