# Are there any methods to convert verb into 3rd person singular form using python3?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp

I want to convert a verb into 3rd person singular form using python3. I tried
[4th Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753021/using-nltk-and-wordnet-how-do-i-convert-simple-tense-verb-into-its-present-pas)

but it gives some errors.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\venv\lib\site-packages\pattern\text\__init__.py", line 609, in _read
    raise StopIteration
StopIteration

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../cardinality.py", line 102, in <module>
    find_one_to_one()
  File ".../cardinality.py", line 95, in find_one_to_one
    print (conjugate(verb='give',tense=PRESENT,number=SG))
  File "...\venv\lib\site-packages\pattern\text\__init__.py", line 2208, in conjugate
    b = self.lemma(verb, parse=kwargs.get("parse", True))
  File "...\venv\lib\site-packages\pattern\text\__init__.py", line 2172, in lemma
    self.load()
  File "...\venv\lib\site-packages\pattern\text\__init__.py", line 2127, in load
    for v in _read(self._path):
RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration
```

Are there any methods to solve this or convert verb into 3rd person singular form?