# using nltk to get back the orginal words with whole sentance to tokenize

Tags: python, nltk

I want to get the original words back.

I know using `nltk` module i can lemmatize the words

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer 
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer() 
lemmatizer.lemmatize(str)
```

I may require another arguments like:

```
lemmatizer.lemmatize(str. "a")
```

or

```
lemmatizer.lemmatize(str, "v")
```

But the problem is I don't have the whole sentence to tokenize.

I want to input a word, it returns the original words without sentence tokenizing.

I want:

was -> be

strongest -> strong

broke -> break

kisses -> kiss

Answer (score 0):

Using NLTK you can do this.
Try the following code:

```
import nltk
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
nltk.download('wordnet')

words = ['gave', 'went', 'going', 'dating']
for word in words:
    print(word + "-->" + WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize(word, 'v'))
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26802243/6068032) also helps you in detail.

Comment: sorry, it only recovers the verb.

Comment: Please specify your requirements.